# Creating TextField list

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a list that users want how many include *TextField* with initial count is two and buttons when pressed adding one more, another when clicked clearing all fields. Then, calculate standard deviation from inputs . What is the best way achieve this ? Make a custom *Row* widget ? With *List* widget or *ListView.builder* widget ?

Comment: What have you tried for it?

Answer (score 0):

```
              children: <Widget>[
                Flexible(
                  fit: FlexFit.tight,
                  flex: 5,
                  child: FractionallySizedBox(
                    widthFactor: 0.9,
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder()
                      ),
                      controller: count,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  fit: FlexFit.tight,
                  flex: 3,
                  child: FractionallySizedBox(

                    widthFactor: 0.9,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      child: Text("Press here"),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                      onPressed: () {
                        fi = int.parse(count.text);
                        setState(() {});
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          fi == null
              ? Offstage()
              : ListView.builder(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: fi,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: index.toString()
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);  }}
```

You can do like this whenever you want to render dynamic textfield then you have to follow like above code thanks